# Adding A CSS from a custom location?

Tags: html, css

If I'm adding a div element to another website is there a way to apply CSS to the div element without adding the CSS to above the  tag? the CSS file is too big and can't fit to style of the div element. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean to another website

Comment: The CSS is in stored im my server while the DIV element is added by the client to his website

Comment: can you give details on what exactly are you trying to achieve? What is the projects purpose? There are probably better solutions.

Comment: Show some example HTML, please.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the link of another website css  in `href` of `link`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="here the link of external website css " />
```

But   don't  since the design may be copyrighted and read carefully the terms and condition and copyright policy

Comment: you mean add this to the DIV element? like <div...><link....>..</div>

Comment: @Rukshan no you have to declare the id or class like them.. and add this link in the header

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not clear enough. Seems like everybody understands it differently. You need to provide some sample code to make it clearer. You might need an external .css file, you might need some jquery scripting, you might need a stylesheet link  as Registered User suggested etc.